# how to alter all view's owner in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, dynamic-sql

In [postgresql-9.2](/questions/tagged/postgresql-9.2) *database* there are `125` *views* stored.Among them 75 *views* *owner* is `sa`.

So,is there any method can I apply to *alter* the *view's* having *owner* `sa` to `postgres`.?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To find out the view associated with the owner `sa`

```
select 
      viewname 
from 
      pg_catalog.pg_views
where
      schemaname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') 
and 
      viewowner = 'sa'
```

---

To `ALTER` view's owner we can use :[`ALTER VIEW  <view_name> OWNER TO <owner_name>`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-alterview.html)

As per documentation:

```
ALTER VIEW [ IF EXISTS ] name ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name SET DEFAULT expression
ALTER VIEW [ IF EXISTS ] name ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name DROP DEFAULT
ALTER VIEW [ IF EXISTS ] name OWNER TO new_owner
ALTER VIEW [ IF EXISTS ] name RENAME TO new_name
ALTER VIEW [ IF EXISTS ] name SET SCHEMA new_schema
ALTER VIEW [ IF EXISTS ] name SET ( view_option_name [= view_option_value] [, ... ] )
ALTER VIEW [ IF EXISTS ] name RESET ( view_option_name [, ... ] )
```

---

finally, to find out the view associated with the owner `sa` and `ALTER` use the following

```
do $$
declare
    myrow record;
begin
for myrow in
select 
     'ALTER VIEW '||quote_ident(v.viewname)||' OWNER TO "postgres";' as viewq
from 
    (select 
      viewname 
from 
      pg_catalog.pg_views
where
      schemaname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') 
and 
      viewowner = 'sa'
    ) v
loop
execute myrow.viewq;
end loop;
end;
$$;
```

Comment: Hi, I am totally new to pl/sql. After a quick search I can't find the type "record" in pl/sql. And also the "v" written after the parentheses seems to be an abbreviation. What's this syntax called? I would like to search for it and learn how to use it in other situations. Thanks!

Comment: @kumom When you refer PostgreSQL search **pl/pgsql**. [Refer declaration from here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/plpgsql-declarations.html). `v` is the alias which I had given to the subselect `select 
      viewname 
from 
      pg_catalog.pg_views
where
      schemaname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') 
and 
      viewowner = 'sa'`

Answer (score 1):

To change *all* the objects owned by sa, you can use [Reassign Owned](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-reassign-owned.html).

To change individual views, you can use [Alter View](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-alterview.html).

You should be able to script the procedure in the second link

Comment: actually this is not what I want